# how to fix the corner problem in a minesweeper?

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I'm coding the reveal function trying to use recursion but I have a problem, when the cycle runs at the corner it doesn't find any cell and returns an error, I've seen that this operator '?.' returns the value or undefined even if there is no value, but I cant figure how this operator could be included in my cycle

```
export function reveal(boardWithMines: CellEnum[][], boardWithOutMines: CellEnum[][], x: number, y: number) {  
    if (boardWithOutMines[x][y] === CellEnum.Hidden || boardWithMines[x][y] === CellEnum.Cero) {
        boardWithOutMines[x][y] = boardWithMines[x][y];
        for (let xOffset = -1; xOffset <= 1; xOffset++) {
            for (let yOffset = -1; yOffset <= 1; yOffset++) {
                reveal(boardWithMines, boardWithOutMines, x + xOffset, y + yOffset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the error that shows up in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bits.png)

Comment: Can you post the error you're seeing? My guess is that you probably need to change those first two array accesses to `boardWithOutMines[x]?.[y]` and `boardWithMines[x]?.[y]` respectively but I don't know for sure without seeing the error.

Comment: I've updated the question showing the error

Comment: Did you try changing the array accesses from my first comment?

Comment: yes, but shows an error tha specify that line with this, "Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression"

Comment: By checking if indices are inside the bounds.

Comment: but if I've used the ?. should be pass that tile if there is no value in, because the limits are defined I guess

Comment: `?.` only works for read access, not for write access, e.g. in `boardWithOutMines[x][y] = boardWithMines[x][y];`. You can use it on the right-hand side of an assignment, but not on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the bounds in the loops:

```
export function reveal(boardWithMines: CellEnum[][], boardWithOutMines: CellEnum[][], x: number, y: number) {  
    if (boardWithOutMines[x][y] === CellEnum.Hidden || boardWithMines[x][y] === CellEnum.Cero) {
        boardWithOutMines[x][y] = boardWithMines[x][y];
        for (let i = Math.max(0, x-1), iMax = Math.min(boardWithMines.length, x+2); i < iMax; ++i) {
            for (let j = Math.max(0, y-1), jMax = Math.min(boardWithMines[i].length, y+2); j < jMax; ++j) {
                reveal(boardWithMines, boardWithOutMines, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code but it shows this error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" I get that is an infinite loop between two blank tiles

Comment: You have an inifinite recursion call. Where is the stop condition? `reveal(boardWithMines, boardWithOutMines, 0, 0);` calls `reveal(boardWithMines, boardWithOutMines, 0, 1);`. `reveal(boardWithMines, boardWithOutMines, 0, 1);` calls `reveal(boardWithMines, boardWithOutMines, 0, 0);`. And so on. You have to mark the tiles that were already processed and don't process them again.

Comment: I realize that the logical operator in the condition it's not | |  should be &&, because that is the way to limit the recursive function but now it doesn't run

Comment: @KevinHernandez If `CellEnum.Cero !== CellEnum.Hidden`, the condition `boardWithOutMines[x][y] === CellEnum.Hidden && boardWithMines[x][y] === CellEnum.Cero` is impossible for the same reason, a number `x` can't contain the value `1` and the value `2` at the same time.